# Possible known ways to improve Back Substitution

Tags: matrices

I am quite new to this field and just implement algorithms.
I am currently using back-substitution as a way to invert a lower triangular matrix.
I would like to ask if there are known ways to improve that back-substitution algorithm,in terms of improving its computations.
Thanks very much!
BR
George

Comment: Do you really need to compute the inverse or you just need to solve a system with this triangular matrix? In the latter case, there's no need to compute the inverse explicitly (even if you want to solve for more right-hand sides).

Comment: Unfortunately,i need to compute the inverse.Is needed for further calculations in the program chain.:D